# Reading serialized array of objects from a file in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, serialization

I have a file in which I have serialized array of objects. I need to stream the file object by object.

My question regarding nodejs stream is that, do I have to take care of my data boundaries? That is, nodejs readable stream emits line by line. So after every line, should I be checking if it is a valid JSON object?

My current implementation is something like this

```
f = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
let buff = '';
f.on('data', (data) => {
   buff += data;
   try {
    process(JSON.parse(buff));
    buff = '';
   } catch (e) {
     return;
   }
}
```

Is there a better alternative? Also do I need to define my own data boundaries?
Note that the objects I need to serialize are continuous. That is, they will be received over time and not once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current implementation, `JSON.parse` will only succeed once, when the entire json is in the buff variable, as this is the only prefix of the whole file that is a valid json.

Instead, you should use [oboejs](http://oboejs.com/examples), a streaming json parser. Here is how to use it:

```js
const parser = oboe().node("!.*", node => {
  console.log(node);
  return oboe.drop;
});

Rx.Observable.from(`[
{"name": "foo"},
{"name": "bar"},
]`).zip(Rx.Observable.interval(10), a=>a).subscribe(char => {
  // console.log(char);
  parser.emit("data", char);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oboe.js/2.1.3/oboe-browser.js"></script>
```

Or adapted to your example:

```
const oboe = require("oboe");
oboe(fs.createReadStream('file.txt')).node("!.*", node => {
    process(node);
    return oboe.drop;
});
```